# How to add icon to cx_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

How can I add icon to exe created by cx_Freeze?

Here is the setup.py:

```
import cx_Freeze
exe = [cx_Freeze.Executable("file.py")]


cx_Freeze.setup( name = "downloads", version = "1.0", options = {"build_exe": {"packages": ["time","clipboard","base64","random","smtplib","binascii",], "include_files": []}}, executables = exe )
```

Answer (score 4):

This is part of the cx_Freeze.Executable object. See the [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#cx-freeze-executable) for more information. Effectively:

```
cx_Freeze.Executable("file.py", icon = "my_icon.ico")
```